# assertってエラーですか？

Tags: python

AssertionErrorが出るのですが、エラーになったら処理が止まるはずだけどスクリプトを見る限りassertの後にも処理があるので、AssertionErrorは注意に過ぎないのかなと思ったのですが、これってassertの後も処理が続いているのですか。

もしもそれがエラーでコードに間違いがあるのならご指摘ください！！

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = '2'

import argparse

from project.LabelType import BaseLabelType
from project.utils import load_model, save_model, model_info
from project.configuration import HarmonicNum
from project.Models.model import seg, sparse_loss
from project.Dataflow import DataFlows

from keras import callbacks
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_paths = {
    "Maestro":  "/data/Maestro",
    "MusicNet": "/mnt/c/Users/Owner/Documents/wsl-music-recommendation-venv/Music-Transcription-with-Semantic-Segmentation-master/musicnet.tar.gz",
    "Maps":     "/data/Maps"
}

dataflow_cls = {
    "Maestro":  DataFlows.MaestroDataflow,
    "MusicNet": DataFlows.MusicNetDataflow,
    "Maps":     DataFlows.MapsDataflow
}

default_model_path = "./model"


def train(
        model, 
        generator_train, 
        generator_val,
        epoch=1,
        callbacks=None, 
        steps=6000, 
        v_steps=3000
    ):

    model.fit_generator(
        generator_train, 
        validation_data=generator_val,
        epochs=epoch,
        steps_per_epoch=steps,
        validation_steps=v_steps,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        max_queue_size=100,
        use_multiprocessing=False
    )

    return model

def main(args):
    if args.dataset not in dataflow_cls:
        raise TypeError

    # Hyper parameters that will be stored for future reuse
    hparams = {}

    # Parameters that will be passed to dataflow
    df_params = {}

    # Handling root path to the dataset
    d_path = dataset_paths[args.dataset]
    if args.dataset_path is not None:
        assert os.path.isdir(args.dataset_path)
        d_path = args.dataset_path

    # Number of channels that model need to know about
    ch_num = len(args.channels)
    channels = args.channels

    # Type of feature to use
    feature_type = "CFP"

    # Output model name
    out_model_name = args.output_model_name

    # Feature length on time dimension
    timesteps = args.timesteps

    # Label type
    l_type = BaseLabelType("frame_onset", timesteps=timesteps)

    # Number of output classes
    out_classes = l_type.get_out_classes()

    # Continue to train on a pre-trained model
    if args.input_model is not None:
        # load configuration of previous training
        feature_type, channels, out_classes, timesteps = model_info(args.input_model)
        ch_num = len(channels)
    else:
        if args.dataset == "MusicNet":
            # Sepcial settings for MusicNet that has multiple instruments presented
            if args.use_harmonic:
                ch_num = HarmonicNum * 2
                channels = [i for i in range(ch_num)]
                feature_type = "HCFP"

    df_params["b_sz"]      = args.train_batch_size
    df_params["phase"]     = "train"
    df_params["use_ram"]   = args.use_ram
    df_params["channels"]  = channels
    df_params["timesteps"] = timesteps
    df_params["out_classes"]  = out_classes
    df_params["dataset_path"] = d_path
    df_params["label_conversion_func"] = l_type.get_conversion_func()

    print("Loading training data")
    df_cls = dataflow_cls[args.dataset]
    train_df = df_cls(**df_params)

    print("Loading validation data")
    df_params["b_sz"]  = args.val_batch_size
    df_params["phase"] = "val"
    val_df = df_cls(**df_params)

    hparams["channels"]       = channels
    hparams["timesteps"]      = timesteps
    hparams["feature_type"]   = feature_type
    hparams["output_classes"] = out_classes

    print("Creating/loading model")
    # Create model
    if args.input_model is not None:
        model = load_model(args.input_model)
    else:
        # Create new model
        model = seg(feature_num=384, input_channel=ch_num, timesteps=timesteps,
                    out_class=out_classes, multi_grid_layer_n=1, multi_grid_n=3)

    # Save model and configurations
    out_model_name = os.path.join(default_model_path, out_model_name)
    if not os.path.exists(out_model_name):
        os.makedirs(out_model_name)

    save_model(model, out_model_name, **hparams)
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss={'prediction': sparse_loss}, metrics=['accuracy'])

    # create callbacks
    earlystop   = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=args.early_stop)
    checkpoint  = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(out_model_name, "weights.h5"), 
                                            monitor="val_loss", save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=True)
    tensorboard = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join("tensorboard", args.output_model_name),
                                        write_images=True)
    callback_list = [checkpoint, earlystop, tensorboard]

    print("Start training")
    # Start training
    train(model, train_df, val_df,
          epoch     = args.epoch,
          callbacks = callback_list,
          steps     = args.steps,
          v_steps   = args.val_steps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Frame-level polyphonic music transcription project done by MCTLab, IIS Sinica.")

    parser.add_argument("dataset", help="One of the Maestro, MusicNet, or Maps", choices=["Maestro", "MusicNet", "Maps"], type=str)
    parser.add_argument("output_model_name", help="Name for trained model. If --input-model is given, then this flag has no effect.", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("dataset_path", help="Path to the root of the dataset that has preprocessed feature", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--use-harmonic", help="Wether to use HCFP feature to train the model", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--multi-instruments", help="Train on transcribing the note played with different instruments", action="store_true")
    # Channel types
    #   0: Z
    #   1: Spec
    #   2: GCoS
    #   3: Ceps
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--channels", help="Use specific channels of feature to train (default: %(default)d)", type=int, nargs="+", default=[1, 3]) 
    parser.add_argument("--use-ram", help="Wether to load the whole dataset into ram", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--timesteps", help="Time width for each input feature (default: %(default)d)", type=int, default=256)

    # Arguments about the training progress
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--epoch", help="Number of epochs to train (default: %(default)d)", type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--steps", help="Training steps for each epoch (default: %(default)d)", type=int, default=2000)
    parser.add_argument("-vs", "--val-steps", help="Validation steps (default: %(default)d)", type=int, default=500)
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input-model", help="If given, then will continue to train on a pre-trained model")
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--train-batch-size", help="Batch size for training phase (default: %(default)d)", type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument("-vb", "--val-batch-size", help="Batch size for validation phase (default: %(default)d)", type=int, default=16)
    parser.add_argument("--early-stop", help="Early stop the training after given # epochs", type=int, default=4)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    main(args)
```

エラー

```
Namespace(channels=[1, 3], dataset='MusicNet', dataset_path='/mnt/c/Users/Owner/Documents/wsl-music-recommendation-venv/Music-Transcription-with-Semantic-Segmentation-master/musicnet.tar.gz', early_stop=4, epoch=10, input_model=None, multi_instruments=False, output_model_name='MrTest', steps=2000, timesteps=256, train_batch_size=8, use_harmonic=False, use_ram=False, val_batch_size=16, val_steps=500)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TrainModel.py", line 187, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "TrainModel.py", line 68, in main
    assert(os.path.isdir(args.dataset_path))
AssertionError
```

Comment: 微妙にずれた理解をしてる感じですね。詳しくは回答してくれる人を待ちましょう。それまではこの辺の記事を参考に。[assert 文ってなに？](https://python.ms/assert/), [7.3. assert 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement), [assert](https://codor.co.jp/python/assert), [unittest --- ユニットテストフレームワーク](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/unittest.html)

Answer (score 1):

AssertionError はエラーです。このエラーを拾っている部分はないため、そのままエラーが出た部分で処理を止め、エラーが出たという出力をしてプログラム全体が終了しています。

エラーに関するチュートリアルがあるので読んでみてください: https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

もし仮に、エラーが起こっている理由が分かっていなくて、それが聞きたいのであれば....

```py
if args.dataset_path is not None:
    assert os.path.isdir(args.dataset_path)
    ...
```

の部分で、`args.dataset_path`がディレクトリであることをテストしていますが、

```
Namespace(..., dataset_path='.../musicnet.tar.gz', ...)
```

の出力から分かるように、`tar.gz`ファイルが渡されているので、`AssertionError`が出ています。

```
    parser.add_argument("dataset_path", help="Path to the root of the dataset that has preprocessed feature", type=str)
```

との説明にある通り、データセットのルートディレクトリへのパスを渡してください。

(ひょっとすると、`musicnet.tar.gz`はデータセットのディレクトリを圧縮して固めたもの？？)